# Create a view with the contents of "self"

Tags: 7, views

I am creating a View that will list all the current user's submissions of a specific content type. It is called "My Submissions".

However, I can't find a way to filter all results to "where author is me". Where could I achieve such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use contexts which is located under advanced to the right.

See below:

[image: User context]

Comment: Image is broken :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a relationship (advanced tab) for author. Then filter by current logged in user. This way also allows you to add author information to the view itself.